# Model error, lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

Hello I have this lambda expression in controller class, and i want to take only modulos to

```
return PartialView( db.AcessosUsuarios               
           .Join(db.Perfils,
           Au => Au.IdPerfil,
           p => p.IdMenu,
           (Au, p) => new { AcessosUsuarios = Au, Perfils = p })
           .Where(x => x.AcessosUsuarios.IdUsuario == Usu)
           .Join(db.Menus,
           p => p.Perfils.IdPerfil,
           Me => Me.IdMenu,
           (Me, p) => new { Menus = Me, Perfils = p })
           .Join(db.Modulos,
           Me => Me.Menus.Perfils.IdMenu,
           Mo => Mo.IdModulo,
           (Me, Mo) => new { Modulos = Mo, Menus = Me, Me.Menus.Perfils.IdMenu })
           .OrderByDescending(Mod => Mod.Modulos.Ordem)
           .Join(db.AcessosAssinantes,
           Mo => Mo.Modulos.IdModulo,
           Aa => Aa.IdModulo,
           (Mo, Aa) => new { Modulos = Mo, AcessosAssinantes = Aa })
           .Where(y => y.AcessosAssinantes.IdAssinante == Ass)
           .Select(s => new { s.Modulos.Modulos})
           .ToList().AsEnumerable());
```

the view

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Modulos>
```

the error is :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`1[Models.Modulos]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.Modulos]'

Anyone can help me?? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've created an anonymous type needlessly with this line:

```
.Select(s => new { s.Modulos.Modulos})
```

Try instead simply (should return an `IEnumerable<Modulos>`):

```
.Select(s => s.Modulos.Modulos)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another question...The OrderBy is not working, you know why??

Comment: @Kate I'm not sure, but maybe it's because you do a join after the order?  You probably want to apply the OrderBy last.